# How to load long epoch column from spark to elastic search as time format?

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, elasticsearch

I have a long data type column(finishedTime) which has epoch time in milliseconds. I'm trying to load this column to elastic search as time format data type so that I can see the timeline but I'm unable to do so.

I tried converting to TimestampType but ES is considering as number datatype

```
val df1=myDF.withColumn("FinishTime",from_unixtime($"finishedTime"/1000).cast(TimestampType)) 
EsSparkSQL.saveToEs(df1,"app_metrics")
```

I'm able to convert to date datatype but loosing the hours,mins,sec

`myDF.withColumn("FinishTime",to_date(from_unixtime($"finishedTime"/1000)))`

Is there any way I can load the epoch time as Date format or any time format?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution here 
https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-hadoop/issues/1173

`.withColumn("FinishTime", date_format(from_unixtime($"finishedTime"/1000),"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"))`

Now ES is automatically recognizing this as date data type